# How to write down the second Fréchet-derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am supposed to express the second Fréchet-Derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ by its partial derivatives. I know how to do this for the first Fréchet-derivative which is basically just the Jacobian matrix but for the second one?- I have honestly no idea.

Comment: Have you an idea for the case $m = 1$?

Comment: Yes, sure. It is just the Hessian matrix.

Comment: Right. Now the difference to the general case is just that we can't write it down so neatly for $m > 1$. We'd need a $3$-dimensional "matrix".

Comment: Yep, but that's exactly the point, why I find this troublesome. I have an idea. I could use this awful notation that is associated with the multi-dimensional Taylor expansion. If nobody has a better idea how to do write this down in a "nicer way", I will use this.

Comment: Well, you could also just write $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial^2 x_1} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1\partial x_2} & \dotsb & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_n}\\\vdots & & & \vdots\\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n \partial x_1} & \dotsb & \dotsb & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n^2}\end{pmatrix}$$ where the components are $m$-dimensional vectors.

Comment: okay thank you. unfortunately ( i think ) , is it not a very common notation, so I'll probably use the Taylor notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you will do with the derivatives after writing them down. Different kinds of computations call for different notational choices. One possibility is to write   $$D^2f = D^2 \begin{pmatrix}f_1 \\ f_2 \\ \vdots \\ f_m\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}H_1 \\ H_2 \\ \vdots \\ H_m\end{pmatrix}$$ 
where $$H_k= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 f_k}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\end{pmatrix}$$ is the Hessian of $f_k$. I.e., a column of matrices.